# ImportError: cannot import name 'request'

Tags: python, request, python-import

I am a windows user. I used the command `pip install requests` to have requests installed, and I also typed`pip install urllib3` to have urllib3 installed. However, I am not able to run this code: `from requests import request`. I got a error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "F:\eclipse\workspace\Overseascredit\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import request
ImportError: cannot import name 'request'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\eclipse\workspace\Overseascredit\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import request
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "F:\eclipse\workspace\Overseascredit\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import request
ImportError: cannot import name 'request'
```

I saw a lot of answers saying that there is another file with duplicate name that occur this error, however, I searched through the fold, I did found one. I even reinstalled my python, but I still got this error. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the requests module and then reinstalling? `pip uninstall requests`

Comment: I'm able to run the code, and I don't have urllib3 installed

Comment: I even uninstalled my python3.5 and installed python2.7. And I installed the requests again. Now the problem become ImportError: No module named urllib3. But the urllib3 fold is sitting at D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
    `from requests import Request`
instead of
    `from requests import request`